# How to avoid WinError 5 when using subprocess module in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use `subprocess` module to run a POS tagger (`TreeTagger`). I have set it up at `D:/TreeTagger` and I have no problem using it using my terminal, here's an example:

```
tag-french test.txt output.txt
```

This assumes we are in the above-mentioned directory. I am trying to do the same using python:

```
subprocess.run([r"D:/TreeTagger", "tag-french", input_file, output_file])
```

Which runs into the following `PermissionError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tagger.py", line 29, in <module>
    tag_file(input_file=str(input), output_file=str(output))
  File "tagger.py", line 17, in tag_file
    subprocess.run([r"D:/TreeTagger", "tag-french", input_file, output_file])
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Now I understand this is due to the first argument since it doesn't change the directory. My python code is in a different directory than `TreeTagger`. I believe this is the source of error but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Try `subprocess.run([r"D:/TreeTagger", "tag-french.exe", input_file, output_file])` ?

Comment: The error remains, I suspect the initial problem is with the first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, the question misses a very important point about how files in `D:/TreeTagger` is arranged which was the root cause of the problem. `tag-french` was not an executive file but rather a windows batch file. So rather than accessing this file, I bypassed this step by calling the executable and parameter file directly. Here's the part of the code which is concerned with it:

```
tagger_location = Path(r"D:/TreeTagger")
    param_file = tagger_location / 'lib' / 'french.par'
    process = subprocess.Popen([str(tagger_location / 'bin' / 'tree-tagger.exe'),
                                str(param_file),
                                input_file,
                                output_file])
    stdout, stderror = process.communicate()
    print("Stdout is -> ", stdout)
    print("StdError is -> ", stderror)
    print("Done and saved to ", output_file)
```

Hope this solves similar problems that someone may face in the future.